# how to get the key of the document when I add an element to my object with this script?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is the structure of my database

```
root
    datizme
       site10
       site22
       site35
```

the script below allows me to obtain all the modifications made in my object datizme but I would like to obtain only the key of the added or removed document or in which modifications have been made.
I did not find a tutorial within my reach

```
    ( function() {
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSsfxIeIaC1bruN12g",
    authDomain: "c-3d423.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://c-3d423.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "c-3d423",
    storageBucket: "c-3d423.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "745995",
    appId: "1:74591495:web:edec51656db3df2"

  };

// Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  
  const preObject = document.getElementById("datizme");
  
  var dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref('datizme');
  
  dbRefObject.on('value', snap => {
     
      preObject.innerText = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);
      
  });


}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect which child node of `datizme` was changed, you can use the `child_changed` event:

```
  dbRefObject.on('child_changed', snap => {     
      console.log(snap.key+" was changed, its new value is "+snap.val());      
  });
```

There are similar events for when a child is added (`child_added`), or removed (`child_removed`).

Comment: I modified the script and tested "child_added" I enter a site I see a deeper path appear when I expected to be at the datizme level and see the name of the site (site48 for example)

Comment: `child_` events fire on the child level. But isn't that exactly what you asked for with "I would like to obtain only the key of the added or removed document or in which modifications have been made"?

Comment: how to get the key of the added site?

Comment: That's `snap.key` as shown in the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had exploited half of the answer I don't know if I should create a new post. My application is "hybrid" on the one hand I use the FIREBASE APIs to read and write data on the other hand this script in a webviewver for real-time updating
When I define the rules as ".read": "auth.uid! = Null", ".write": "auth.uid! = null" I can continue to read and write but the update does not take place even when the author of the script proposes to add the authentication in the script with email and password